# functions as applicative functors (Haskell / LYAH)

Tags: haskell, applicative

Chapter 11 of *Learn You a Haskell* introduces the following definition:

```
instance Applicative ((->) r) where
    pure x = (\_ -> x)
    f <*> g = \x -> f x (g x)
```

Here, the author engages in some uncharacteristic hand-waving ("The instance implementation for <*> is a bit cryptic, so it's best if we just [show it in action without explaining it]"). I'm hoping someone here might help me figure it out.

According to the applicative class definition, `(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`

In the instance, substituting `((->)r)` for `f`: `r->(a->b)->(r->a)->(r->b)`

So the first question, is how do I get from that type to `f <*> g = \x -> f x (g x)`?

But even if I take that last formula for granted, I have trouble making it agree with examples I give to GHCi. For example:

```
Prelude Control.Applicative> (pure (+5)) <*> (*3) $ 4
17
```

This expression instead appears consistent with `f <*> g = \x -> f (g x)` (note that in this version `x` doesn't appear after `f`.

I realize this is messy, so thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: In the example, remeber that `pure (+5)` discards its first argument, so it's `const (+5) 4 $ (4 * 3)` or `4 * 3 + 5` which is consistent with `(+5) . (*3) $ 4`. Additionally, `f <*> g = \x -> f (g x)` is of type `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)` which neither typechecks with `pure (+ 5)  <*> (* 3) $ 4` nor the class declaration of `Applicative`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

First of all, remember how `fmap` is defined for applicatives:

```
fmap f x = pure f <*> x
```

This means that your example is the same as `(fmap (+ 5) (* 3)) 4`. The `fmap` function for functions is just composition, so your exact expression is the same as `((+ 5) . (* 3)) 4`.

Now, let's think about why the instance is written the way it is. What `<*>` does is essentially apply a function in the functor to a value in the functor. Specializing to `(->) r`, this means it applies a function returned by a function from `r` to a value returned by a function from `r`. A function that returns a function is just a function of two arguments. So the real question is this:  how would you apply a function of two arguments (`r` and `a`, returning `b`) to a value `a` returned by a function from `r`?

The first thing to note is that you have to return a value of type `(->) r` which means the result also has to be a function from `r`. For reference, here is the `<*>` function:

```
f <*> g = \x -> f x (g x)
```

Since we want to return a function taking a value of type `r`, `x :: r`. The function we return has to have a type `r -> b`. How can we get a value of type `b`? Well, we have a function `f :: r -> a -> b`. Since `r` is going to be the argument of the result function, we get that for free. So now we have a function from `a -> b`. So, as long as we have some value of type `a`, we can get a value of type `b`. But how do we get a value of type `a`? Well, we have another function `g :: r -> a`. So we can take our value of type `r` (the parameter `x`) and use it to get a value of type `a`.

So the final idea is simple: we use the parameter to first get a value of type `a` by plugging it into `g`. The parameter has type `r`, `g` has type `r -> a`, so we have an `a`. Then, we plug both the parameter and the new value into `f`. We need both because `f` has a type `r -> a -> b`. Once we plug both an `r` and an `a` in, we have a `b1`. Since the parameter is in a lambda, the result has a type `r -> b`, which is what we want.

Comment: Wow, flashback to the abstract algebra class that cleaned my clock ten years ago! I really do appreciate the patient detail of this response. You're a gifted teacher, and I hope you'll at least consider academia among your post-graduate options.

Comment: Fun fact: The definition of `<*>` for `((->) r)` can be derived for free. Try plugging the type (`(r -> a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)`) into Djinn!

Comment: I found the above explanation really useful but a bit difficult to follow. If anyone wants more to work with, here's an explanation of how I applied the above to a real example so that I could better understand it: https://wjdhamilton.blogspot.co.uk/2016/08/f-f-x-g-x.html

Answer (score 31):

Going through your original question, I think there's one subtle but very key point that you might have missed. Using the original example from LYAH:

```
(+) <$> (+3) <*> (*100) $ 5
```

This is the same as:

```
pure (+) <*> (+3) <*> (*100) $ 5
```

The key here is the `pure` before `(+)`, which has the effect of boxing `(+)` as an Applicative. If you look at how `pure` is defined, you can see that to unbox it, you need to provide an additional argument, which can be anything. Applying `<*>` to `(+) <$> (+3)`, we get

```
\x -> (pure (+)) x ((+3) x)
```

Notice in `(pure (+)) x`, we are applying `x` to `pure` to unbox `(+)`. So we now have

```
\x -> (+) ((+3) x)
```

Adding `(*100)` to get `(+) <$> (+3) <*> (*100)` and apply `<*>` again, we get

```
\y -> (\x -> (+) ((+3) x)) y ((*100) y) {Since f <*> g = f x (g x)}

5  -> (\x -> (+) ((+3) x)) 5 ((*100) 5)

(\x -> (+) ((+3) x)) 5 (500)

5 -> (+) ((+3) 5) (500)

(+) 8 500

508
```

So in conclusion, the `x` after `f` is NOT the first argument to our binary operator, it is used to UNBOX the operator inside `pure`.

Comment: This is an absolutely critical point! It explains both the role of x and also why the number of parameters that the first function accepts must equal the number of applied functions.

Comment: @JamesHamilton This is the answer that hits the nail on the head. It ought to be *the* answer.

Comment: You're right, but given that it's been several years since I asked the question I am unsure that I can change my preferred answer

Comment: LYAH makes it sound in their description like `(+3) <*> (*100)` is a well-formed Haskell expression, and the confusion with the associativity between `$` and `<$>` makes the matter worse. Writing without infix makes it far easier to understand: `(<*>) ((+) <$> (+3)) (*100)` or `(<*>) ((<*>) (pure (+)) (+3)) (*100) $ 5`.

Answer (score 20):

> “In the instance, substituting `((->)r)` for `f`: `r->(a->b)->(r->a)->(r->b)`”

Why, that's not right. It's actually `(r->(a->b)) -> (r->a) -> (r->b)`, and that is the same as `(r->a->b) -> (r->a) -> r -> b`. I.e., we map an infix and a function which returns the infix' right-hand argument, to a function which takes just the infix' LHS and returns its result. For example,

```
Prelude Control.Applicative> (:) <*> (\x -> [x]) $ 2
[2,2]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### How to understand `Function as Functor` and `Function as Applicative`?

First, how to understand function as functor?

We can regard functor as an empty box such as:

```hs
instance Functor Maybe where 
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
    fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x) 
    fmap f Nothing = Nothing
```

there, `Maybe` type can be seen as an **empty box with one slot** which take a type to generate a concrete type `Maybe a`. In the `fmap` function:

- The first parameter is a function, which maps from a to b;
- **The second parameter is a value of the type with the slot filled(concrete type), this concrete type is generated by type constructor and has the type *f a* (*f* is `Maybe`, so *f a* is `Maybe a` ).**

When we implement function functors, for function functors must have two parameters to make a type `a -> b`, if we want our function functor has exactly one slot, we should first fill a slot, so the type constructor of function functor is ((->) r):

```hs
instance Functor ((->) r) where 
    fmap f g = (\x -> f (g x))
```

As the same as the `fmap` function in `Maybe` Functor, we should regard the second parameter *g* as a value of a concrete type which is generate by *f* (*f* equals `(->) r`), so *f a* is `(->) r a` which can be seen as `r -> a`. Finally, it is not difficult to understand that the *g x* in the `fmap` function cannot be seen as `r -> x`,  it is just a function application which can be seen as `(r -> a) x`, also `(x -> a)`.

Finally, it is not hard to understand that the <*> function in Applicative function `(->) r`  can be implemented as following:

```hs
<*> :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
<*> :: (r -> a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
<&> :: (a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
f <*> g = \r -> f r (g r)
```

for *g r* will map *r* to *a*, *f r a* will map *r, a* to *b*, so the whole lambda function can be seen as `r -> b`,  also `f b`. For an instance:

```hs
((+) <*> (+3)) 5
```

the result is 5 + (5 + 3) = 13.

#### How to understand in functions as applicatives, `(+) <$> (+3) <*> (*100) $ 5` = 508?

We know `(+)` has type: `Num a, a -> a -> a`;

We also know `(+3)` and `(*100)` has type: `Num r, a, r -> a`;

`(+) <$> (+3)` equals `pure (+) <*> (+3)`, where `:t pure (+)` equals `Num _, a, _ -> a -> a -> a`

In another words, the `pure (+)` simply takes a `_` parameter whatever and return the `+` operator, the parameter `_` has no effect on the final return value. `pure (+)` also maps the return value of function `(+3)` to a function. Now for

```hs
f <*> g = \r -> f r (g r)
```

we can apply the operators and get:

```hs
pure (+) <*> (+3) = 
    \r -> f r (gr) =
    \r -> + (gr) =
    \r -> + (r + 3) =
    \r x -> x + (r + 3)
```

it has the type `r -> x -> a`. We then calculate `pure (+) <*> (+3) <*> (*100)` using the definition of <*>, and get:

```hs
pure (+) <*> (+3) <*> (*100) = 
    \r -> f r (gr) =
    \r -> (r + 3) + (gr)
    \r -> (r + 3) + (r * 100)
```

then we apply this function with parameter 5, we get:

```hs
(5 + 3) + (5 * 100) = 508
```

we can simply think this applicative style as first to calculate the value after `<$>` and sum them up with the operator before `<$>`. In last example, this operator is a binary operator equals `(+)`, we can replace it with a triple operator `(\x y z -> [x,y,z])`, so the following equation holds:

```hs
(\x y z -> [x,y,z]) <$> (+3) <*> (*2) <*> (/2) $ 5 = [8.0,10.0,2.5]
```