# Using liftA2 with functions

Tags: haskell

I am wondering how this works.

```
x 9001 = True
x _ = False

g 42 = True
g _ = False

(liftA2 (||) x g) 42 = True

liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
x :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> Bool
g :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> Bool
```

How does the type of x and g (a -> Bool) correspond to what liftA2 expects (f a)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [functions as applicative functors (Haskell / LYAH)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810889/functions-as-applicative-functors-haskell-lyah)

Comment: (Hint: remember that `liftA2 f x y = f <$> x <*> y`, and note that the `Applicative` instance involved here is the one for functions.)

Answer (score 5):

Remember that `((->) a)` is a `Monad` (also known as the reader monad), and hence an `Applicative` too. Taken [from the source for base](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-641)

```
instance Applicative ((->) a) where
  pure = const
  (<*>) f g x = f x (g x)
```

Then, `liftA2 (||) x g` is the function of type `(Num a, Eq a) => a -> Bool` that checks if either of the results of applying the argument to `x` and `g` is `True`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that. Haven't read the reader monad chapter yet. Don't know why they gave it as an example when it hasn't been covered.