# Example of functions as applicatives, in foldMap and filter for foldables

Tags: haskell, applicative

In the first hunk, `filterF` is implemented with `foldMap`

```
import Data.List

pred :: a -> Bool
pred = undefined

wrapperOfA :: (Applicative f, Monoid (f a)) => a -> Bool -> f a 
wrapperOfA a condition = if condition then pure a else mempty

-- foldMap :: (Foldable t, Monoid  f a) => (a -> f a) -> t a -> f a
filterF :: (Applicative f, Foldable t, Monoid (f a)) => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> f a 
filterF pred = foldMap ((<*>) wrapperOfA  pred)
```

```
filterF (<3) [5,4,3,2,1] :: [Int]
-- [2,1]
```

... which utilises some `Applicative`'s apply function, aka `<*>` typically infixed. Now, the type of `<*>` is:

```
:t (<*>)
--(<*>) :: forall (f :: * -> *) a b. Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

But replacing it with a hole gives its type as

```
-- (a0 -> Bool -> f0 a0) -> (a -> Bool) -> a -> f a
-- namely, from typechecking
filterF :: (Applicative f, Foldable t, Monoid (f a)) => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> f a 
filterF pred = foldMap (_ wrapperOfA pred)
-- Found hole ‘_’ with type: (a0 -> Bool -> f0 a0) -> (a -> Bool) -> a -> f a
-- Where: ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for interactive:IHaskell136.filterF :: (Applicative f, Foldable t, Monoid (f a)) => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> f a at :1:12
--       ‘f’ is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for interactive:IHaskell136.filterF :: (Applicative f, Foldable t, Monoid (f a)) => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> f a at :1:12
--       ‘a0’ is an ambiguous type variable
--       ‘f0’ is an ambiguous type variable
-- Relevant bindings include
--   pred :: a -> Bool (bound at :2:9)
--   filterF :: (a -> Bool) -> t a -> f a (bound at :2:1)
-- In the expression: _
-- In the first argument of ‘foldMap’, namely ‘(_ wrapperOfA pred)’
-- In the expression: foldMap (_ wrapperOfA pred)
```

Basically, `wrapperOfA` does not look like `f (a -> b)` as `<*>` would imply, nor does `pred` look like type `f a`. Yet it works and type checks - why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<*>` uses the [Applicative instance for functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11811057/3946502)

```
 (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

where `f` is a `(->) r` , namely a function from the `r` domain.

Substituting, the first argument of `<*>`  becomes a *function from the `r` domain AND the `a` domain, then returning a `b`* (a function of 2 arguments, since type r -> (a -> b) is equivalent to r -> a -> b), and the second argument becomes a *function from the `r` domain returning an `a`*.

To produce a `(->) r b`, we should apply the second-argument (a function) to the `r` parameter, and the resulting `a` is passed as a second argument to the thing in front of `<*>`. That is,

```
(<*>) wrapperOfA pred r = wrapperOfA r (pred r)
```

This leads me to a **follow-up question/comment** to bring the focus to `foldMap` and filterF which I now rename `filterH`.

```
    filterH :: (a -> Bool) -> t a -> h a
    foldMap :: (a -> f a) -> t a -> f a
    wrapperOfA <*> pred :: a -> h a
```

where `h` is *any* applicative and monoid with corresponding pure and mempty but is as yet undefined. So I needed to request a return type eg `::[Int]` in order for it to compile&evaluate. Can filterH be used without having to specify my own type `h`? Am I missing something in this solution?

This is a question from the textbook "haskell programming from first principles", in the foldables section.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your follow-up question. You can use `filterH` without specifying a concrete choice of `h` in the same way you can use `(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` without specifying a concrete choice of `f`.

Comment: (By the way, it's better not to add follow-up questions to answers. The usual thing to do is using comments for that; or, if the question drifts too far from the original topic, asking a new question.)

Answer (score 4):

The `(<*>)` there uses the [`Applicative` instance for functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11810889/2751851). In...

```
-- Writing it infix, for the sake of clarity. 
filterF pred = foldMap (wrapperOfA <*> pred)
```

... `wrapperOfA` has type `a -> (Bool -> f a)`, and `pred` has type `a -> Bool`. That being so, `wrapperOfA <*> pred` has type `a -> f a`, as expected. If we substitute the implementation of `(<*>)` for functions (see the question linked to above for details), we get...

```
filterF pred = foldMap (\a -> wrapperOfA a (pred a))
```

... which makes it clear what is going on.

Comment: Writing it as `\a -> wrapperOfA a $ pred a` makes the translation more clear, that `(<*>)` is function application threaded with environment `a`: `wrapperOfA <*> pred`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll find easier this solution:

```hs
import Control.Conditional (select)

filterF :: (Applicative f, Foldable t, Monoid (f a)) => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> f a
filterF f = foldMap (select f pure mempty)
```

Here, `select` is just a functional if-then-else, where you provide functions for the condition, the true case and the else case.