# Possible to write bigram (or ngram) function using reduce in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reduce, n-gram

I know that the `.reduce` function in Javascript has a notion of `previous` and `current` variables "built-in", so to speak, in its definition. So I'm curious why this doesn't work:

```
var bigrams = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(previous, current) {
  return [previous, current]
});
```

I do not think that means what I think it means, because now `bigrams` contains:

```
[[[[0,1],2],3],4]
```

When what I wanted was:

```
[[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
```

I think it has to do with the fact that the result should be pushed into the accumlator (which should perhaps be an empty array, something like: `arr.reduce(/*magic*/, [])`?

- Should I not be using `.reduce` to do this?
- If so, is there another "functional" way to do it?
- How do I avoid this nesting behavior?

Comment: It's a *reduce* (*fold*) function where `previous` is the *accumulator* (and shouldn't be named `previous`), not a map function that has access to its previous item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way reduce works is that the output of one call is used as the input to the next call.  If we name your function `f`, your call is equivalent to:

```
f(f(f(f(0, 1), 2), 3), 4)
```

In other words, the `previous` does not mean "previous item in the original array", it means "result of the previous call to the function".

`reduce` is not a great choice for this task, because, as its name implies, it is aimed at *reducing* an array to a single value.  One "functional" way to do this is to use `zip` and zip the array with its tail (all but the first element), as shown in [this Haskell example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2546533/1427416).  However, Javascript doesn't have a zip function builtin.  Using the second `zip` implementation from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10284006/1427416):

```
function zip() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    var shortest = args.length==0 ? [] : args.reduce(function(a,b){
        return a.length<b.length ? a : b
    });

    return shortest.map(function(_,i){
        return args.map(function(array){return array[i]})
    });
}
```

You can do:

```
var x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
zip(x, x.slice(1))
```

However, in JavaScript, I think most people would probably just do it iteratively, like in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566379/how-to-get-all-pairs-of-array-javascript).